# openGL Extensions availability and different GPU brands

Tags: opengl, gpu, textures, glfw, openframeworks

I'm using openFrameworks on Windows, which uses GLFW and GLEW, and I'm having issues regarding extensions availability on different GPUs brands.

Basically, if I run my program on openGL 2, the extensions are available. But if I change to openGL 3.2 or higher, all the extensions became unavailable on Nvida (tested on a* GTX1080) and Intel (*UHD), but not on AMD (*Vega Mobile GL/GH and RX 5700).

This translates to not being able to use GL_ARB_texture_float, and therefore my compute shaders don't work as intended.

I'm using openGL 4.3, for the compute shader support and for support of the Intel GPU. All drivers are up to date and all GPU support GL_ARB_texture_float.

Also, enabling the extension on the GLSL does nothing.

This is how openFrameworks makes the context:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_OPENGL_API);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, settings.glVersionMajor);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, settings.glVersionMinor);
if((settings.glVersionMajor==3 && settings.glVersionMinor>=2) || settings.glVersionMajor>=4)
{
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
}
if(settings.glVersionMajor>=3)
{
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
}
```

Not sure what is going on, nor exactly how to search for an issue like this. Any pointers are welcome!

Comment: Are you sure you are using GLEW 2.x and not the ancient GLEW 1.x which had a horrible bug when using core profiles?

Answer (score 6):

ARB_texture_float is an ancient extension that was incorporated into OpenGL proper in 3.0. That is, if you ask for 3.2, you can just use floating-point formats for textures. They're always available.

Furthermore, later GL versions add more floating-point formats.

Since there is no core profile of OpenGL less than version 3.2, I suspect that these implementations are simply not advertising extensions that have long since been part of core OpenGL if you ask for a core profile.

Comment: I see, but then why does a texture with a internal format of GL_RGBA16F work on AMD but not on Nvidia or Intel?

Comment: @Hubris: How do you know that it "doesn't work"?

Comment: Basically, I'm using a bunch of textures and compute shaders to do an animation, and nothing is written in some of them. Your answer steer me on a different direction, and I realized that openFrameworks allocates images and textures with a different default. Now I'm enforcing GL_RGBA16F on all, so now I'm starting to see parts of the animation on the Nvidia and Intel GPUs, but not all of them behave has expected. On the AMD, it just keeps on working, and that's what I don't understand. openFrameworks does not differentiate between GPU vendors.

Comment: @Hubris: Then this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Probably, but isn't core issue is still the same? That is, the different behavior (AMD vs. Intel/Nvidia) on something that, according to what I learned and was able to search, should be the same? I couldn't find more stuff on the difference between brands, hence my asking for pointers.

Comment: @Hubris: "*but isn't core issue is still the same?*" No. You asked about what extensions are deemed to be available or not. What you're looking for is why your compute shaders aren't writing to images correctly. That's an XY problem: you *think* the solution is extensions and formats, while the fact that you mentioned "compute shaders", "textures", and "nothing is written" tells me that your actual problem has nothing to do with the GPU or extensions. So post a new question about your actual problem *including* an [mcve]